# The length of pre-defined boolean array gets changed while executing code

Tags: java, arrays

I have made an array boolean prime[] to generate all the prime numbers between 1 to N. Initially the length of array is N+1. when I execute the for loop with condition for(int i=2; i*i<=N;i++) the value of c(total prime numbers) < N but with condition  for(int i=2; i<=N;i++) the value of c(total prime numbers) > N .How's that possible?

```
public int exactly3Divisors(int N)
    {
        int n = N;
        boolean prime[] = new boolean[n+1]; 
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
            prime[i] = true; 

        for(int p = 2; p*p <=n; p++) 
        { 
            // If prime[p] is not changed, then it is a prime 
            if(prime[p] == true) 
            { 
                // Update all multiples of p 
                for(int i = p*p; i <= n; i += p) 
                    prime[i] = false; 
            } 
        } 


        int num=0;
        int c=0;
        System.out.println("Length "+ prime.length);

        for(int i=2; i<=N;i++){ //if we change i<=N with i*i<=N works fine

            if(prime[i]==true)
             c++;
           if(prime[i]==true && i*i <=N){
                 num++;
        //     System.out.print(i+"-"+(i*i)+" ");
           }

        }
        System.out.print("c = "+c) ; 
        return num;
    }
```

The value of c expected must be < N but it actually way larger than N

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular How do [I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: How do you check that `c` is "way larger"? Let me guess, you print the result of your `exactly3Divisors(...)` call?

Comment: Try with `System.out.println("c = " + c);` instead of `System.out.print("c = " + c);`. See some difference?

Comment: For Input: N = 999999 
c = 7849837386 while the value of c is  incremented only when prime[i]==true and prime.length = N+1 and the outcome c>>N